# How to insert a "," in between each char of a string

Tags: java, string, loops, split, substring

Im at a point in my program where I need to set marks in a string before I pass it through another method, I have it so that every 4th char will have a "|" inserted, this is to mark a row break. Not I want to take each char in between the outter marks "|" and put a ",". that two char array method wont work here otherwise I would have tryed to use that but I'm not looking for a char array.

```
public static String matrixFormatter(String x){

x = x.substring(0, 4) + "|" + x.substring(4, x.length());
    return x;
 }
```

this works so far, now I want to add a "," between each char, I thought the code below would work and this would be easy but I was wrong.

```
public static String matrixFormatter(String x){

for(int i = 0; i<=x.length(); i+=4){
    for(int j = 0; j<=x.length(); i++){
    x = x.substring(0, i) + "|" + x.substring(i, x.length());
    x = x.substring(0, j) + "|" + x.substring(j, x.length());
    }
}
return x;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in one method:

```
public static String matrixFormatter(String x) {
    List<String> chars = Arrays.asList(x.split(""));
    String result = chars.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < chars.size(); i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0)
            result += "|" + chars.get(i);
        else
            result += "," + chars.get(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

calling with:

```
System.out.println(matrixFormatter("12345678"));
```

outputs:

```
1,2,3,4|5,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you question correctly, you should probably add some input and expected output to be more clearer.

```
    String a = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    String a2 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            if(i % 4 == 0){
               a2 += "|";
            } else{
               a2 += ",";
            }
        }
        a2 += a.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(a2);
```

This will produce the output `a,b,c,d|e,f,g,h|i,j,k,l|m,n,o,p`

Answer (score 0):

The code below adds a "," between characters in the string.

```
public static String matrixFormatter(String x){
      String result;
      for(int i = 0; i<x.length()-1; i++){
             result += x.substring(i, i+1) + ",";
       }
      return result+",";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
    s = s.replaceAll("(?<=.)(?=.)", ",");
```

Comment: Care to explain the regex? (VLQRQ)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `StringBuffer` and also with `Joiner` of `Guava` library:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "example";
    System.out.println(withBuilder(s));
    System.out.println(withJoiner(s));
}

private static String withJoiner(String s) {
    return Joiner.on(",").join(Chars.asList(s.toCharArray()));
}

private static String withBuilder(String s)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s);
    int index = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() ; i++)
    {
        builder.insert(index, ",");
        index +=2;
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Output is:

```
e,x,a,m,p,l,e,
e,x,a,m,p,l,e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String matrixFormatter(String x) {
  resultstr = "";
  int i = 0;
  while(i < x.length()) {
    // If end of string: only add character.
    if (i == x.length() - 1) {
      resultstr += x.substring(i, i + 1);
    } else {
      if ( ((i + 1) % 4) == 0) {
        resultstr += x.substring(i, i + 1)  + "|";
      } else {
        resultstr += x.substring(i, i + 1)  + ",";
      }
    }
    i++;
  }
  return resultstr;
}
```

Haven't got Java installed but tested the concept via PHP-code:

```
function matrixFormatter($x) {
  $resultstr = "";
  $i = 0;
  while($i < strlen($x)) {
    if ($i == strlen($x) - 1) {
      $resultstr .= $x[$i];
    } else {
      if ( (($i + 1) % 4) == 0) {
        $resultstr .= $x[$i] . "|";
      } else {
        $resultstr .= $x[$i] . ",";
      }
    }
    $i++;
  }
  return $resultstr;
}
```

matrixFormatter("abcdefghijklmnopq") returns "a,b,c,d|e,f,g,h|i,j,k,l|m,n,o,p|q".